# Alinhar itens a direita dentro de um flexbox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando bootstrap 4 e essa classe css, para alinhar verticalmente meus itens:

```
.vertical-align {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.vertical-align > [class^="col-"],
.vertical-align > [class*=" col-"] {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

no meu HTML tenho o seguinte:

```
<div class="row vertical-align">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="catergorias">
            <ul class="list-inline categorias_topo">
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">Categoria 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">Categoria 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">Categoria 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">Categoria 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        BUSCA
    </div>
</div>
```

Com isso, todos esse conteudo está alinhado à esquerda.

Como posso alinhar, por exemplo, essa lista (ul>li) à direita?

Nada está funcionando.

Segue print: http://prntscr.com/b23pia

Segue Fiffle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xcottg08/

Comment: Seria interessante você utilizar algum editor online, como por exemplo o JSFiddle já que o código não é complexo.

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe inclui o Fiddle.

Comment: Você esta querendo algo assim? https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/qecwtn4k/

Comment: mais ou menos isso... será que se eu usar o NAV no lugar do UL é melhor?

Answer (score -1):

No seu CSS, na linha onde voce colocou:

```
justify-content: flex-start;
```

mude para:

```
justify-content: flex-end;
```